# Finding negative number in a string

Tags: unix, grep

I am given the data file of user eye sights. How could I find only the users with the negative right eye sight using grep?

The data is ordered as such (Name,Right,Left)

```
$ Bruce,-4.5,-3.5
$ Amanda,+2.0,+2.0
$ Roger,+3.0,-1.5
```

What I have so far:

```
$ grep '\-\d*' <file>
```

Output:

```
Bruce,-4.5,-3.5   
Roger,+3.0,-1.5
```

Expected output:

```
Bruce,-4.5,-3.5
```

Comment: Is `$` part of your file?

Comment: Looks like you could just `grep ,- file`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -E '.*,-[0-9]+.[0-9]+,.*' file
Bruce,-4.5,-3.5
```

You can also use `awk` and separate the `,` with `FS`

```
$ awk -F, '$2~/-[0-9]+.[0-9]+/ {print}' file
Bruce,-4.5,-3.5
```